# ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu, xampp

[image]

Por favor ayúdenme, sucede que estoy usando un entorno xampp en ubuntu y en el momento de iniciar mysql por consola me sucede este error por favor ayúdenme se los agradecería bastante !!

Comment: Ya pasaste por aquí? A lo mejor te ilumine un poco: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11990708/error-cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-var-run-mysqld-mysq

Comment: Buenaso muchas gracias ya solucioné !!

Comment: La solución encontré aquí https://stackoverflow.com/a/50858499/9717014

Comment: Hola Juan. Ya que has encontrado la respuesta, en vez de ponerla en un comentario, intenta adaptarla y ponerla en una respuesta a tu propia pregunta. mira [answer] para más info. un saludo

Comment: En estos casos lo que me ha funcionado a mi es desinstalar MySQL por separado y volverlo a instalar.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes utilizar el comando

```
/opt/lampp/var/mysql -u root -p
```

Ingresar la contraseña y debería funcionar.

No hay demasiada explicación en la formulación, pero lo que sucede es que está tratando de conectar a una servidor MySQL, pero en LAMPP, por lo que el archivo socket de conexión está en otro directorio (`/opt/lampp/var/`).

Comment: Probé la respuesta antes de publicarla. Y creo que es una respuesta posible. No hay demasiada explicación en la formulación, pero lo que sucede es que esta tratando de conectar a una servidor mysql, pero en lampp, por lo que el archivo socket de conexión esta en otro directorio (/opt/lampp/var/).

Answer (score 0):

La respuesta esta en este enlace !! solo para quienes usan un entorno XAMPP en linux https://stackoverflow.com/a/50858499/9717014

Usando XAMPP en ubuntu:

1. Crear una carpeta llamda **mysqld** dentro de **/var/run/**. Esto se puede realizar con el comando `sudo mkdir /var/run/mysqld`.
2. Crear un enlace simbólico apuntando al archivo **mysql.sock** el cual es creado al arrancar el servidor XAMPP. Esto se puede realizar con el comando `sudo ln -s /opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock`.

> **Nota:** El archivo *mysql.sock* es creado cuando arranca el servidor y borrado cuando el servidor para, así que algunas veces el enlace simbólico creado puede aparecer como roto ( apunta aun archivo inexistente ) pero debería seguir funcionando ya sea que inicies el servidor con `sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start` o algún otro método.

3. Iniciar el servidor si es que no está corriendo e intentar ejecutar nuevamente el programa que daba error.

---

El mysqld de xampp crea un socket en una ubicación: `/opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock`, pero el resto de programas espera que esté en `/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock`.

El error se soluciona al crear un enlace simbólico entre lo esperado y lo que existe.

Comment: puedes traducir la respuesta y luego coloca el enlace de referencia, recuerda que hay personas de habla hispana que no manejan el ingles